# Anyway to tell NetBeans not to store files locally?

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp

I am trying out using NetBeans 6.9.1 for PHP web development.

I want to view my file tree and edit files directly on my test server via FTP.

Is there a way to tell NetBeans not to store the files locally?

The reason is I do not want to worry about the local files being out of sync with the remote files.

I did a quick test, opened a file, made some changes and saved them. On my test server the changes were there, so far this was good. this was only a test, so I wanted to revert my changes. Since my test server is under Mercurial version control, I SSH'd to my remote server and did a revert. Now the server is back to normal. However, I open the file again in NetBeans and my changes are still there, because NetBeans is showing me the local copy not the remote file.

Besides that, I don't need to have a ton of files saved locally when I wont be making changes to most of them very often.

Comment: You can use version control inside NetBeans as well, just as a tip. This would solve some of your problems. I don't know whether NetBeans can use only remote files though.

Comment: Agree with @Björn, FTP should be replaced with SSH-based version control such as GIT or SVN. It's more secure, and provides project backups should anything go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux, you can put your entire project on an FTP site and manipulate the files directly without having to sync it. For Windows, check out a little utility called [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertechnologies.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html), which can map FTP locations (among others) to a drive letter.

Comment: Can you please give me instructions on how to do so in Linux? I am using Ubuntu, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly, but you can create a mount point in your home directory to the FTP location. Nautilus may actually do this automatically, in which case you'd only have to find it once it's connected. Then all you have to do is copy/paste it into Netbeans. Check out this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=203572

Comment: Using ubuntu too.. Didn't think to try this, awesome.

Comment: Check out SSHFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) for mounting sftp connections on linux

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - Install Aptana

I struggled with this for like 3 hours. We are a team working on the same webserver (thus, same files) using sftp (no version control) and Netbeans.

The problem is, Netbeans doesn't warns you when you are writing over an old version of the remote file nor downloads the latest version of the remote files automatically (you have to manually download each or all of them).

I found the answer [in this question (superuser)](https://superuser.com/questions/93539/always-redownload-a-file-when-opening-it-in-netbeans-ide-6-8). Saved my life.